# maven 3 SNAPSHOTS are not deployed to the right location

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I am using maven 3 and nexus for deploying our artifacts toa repository,

I saw that the non-unique option was deprecated in maven 3 so all SNAPSHOTS artifacts are being deployed with a timestamp and I am cool with that, the problem is that it looks like all artifacts are not under the version I specified (0.6-SNAPSHOT) so when I try to get this dependency the build is failing because it can't find it.

***This is the dependency definition in the pom:***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.globals</groupId>
    <artifactId>globals-general</artifactId>
    <version>0.6-SNAPSHO</version>
</dependency>
```

***And this is the error I get when I try to get the dependency:***

```
Failed to execute goal on project mprest-mgrid-infra-cache: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mprest.mgrid.infra:mprest-mgrid-infra-cache:jar:0.6-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mprest.mgrid.globals:mprest-mgrid-globals-general:jar:0.6-SNAPSHOT ->
```

***This is my pom relevant part:***

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

***And this is the structure:***

[image]

Comment: I see no error in what you are doing. Maven deploys 0.6-SNAPSHOT as some timestamp to Nexus, and if you declare a dependency on 0.6-SNAPSHOT, the latest timestamp should be loaded. Try to give us more information about what you did.

Comment: The distributionManagement is not relevant to consume artifacts. That should be configured in your `settings.xml` and pointing to the repository group in Nexus...

Comment: The distributionManagement is also configured in the settings.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is ok,
under 0.6-SNAPSHOT there are all the 0.6-SNAPSHOTs with time stamps,
and maven-metadata.xml pointing to the latest artifact.

It turns out I needed to add the repositories in a certain way inside the settings.xml in order for me to be able to get the artifacts.

This is what it looks like:

```
 <servers>
    <server>
     <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
   </server>
   <server>
     <id>nexus-releases</id>
   </server>
     <server>
     <id>maven-group</id>
   </server>
 </servers>

 <mirrors>
   <mirror>
     <id>maven-group</id>
     <name>maven-group</name>
     <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>
     <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
   </mirror>
 </mirrors>

 <profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
         <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
         <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
         <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
       </repository>

       <repository>
         <id>nexus-releases</id>
         <url>http://nexus:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
         <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
         <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
</profiles>

</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last version of Nexus API is documented the way to retrieve the latest version of a component, filtering by repository, group, artifact and base version

Example:
http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=maven-snapshots&maven.groupId=org.foo.bar&maven.artifactId=project&maven.baseVersion=1.2.3-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=jar

Reference documentation:
https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-SearchComponents

Maybe you need to download the desired jar, previously, and latter run the Maven goal